# How to access Private files in CDN within react Project

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, translation, cdn, i18next

This is for language translation on web page. I want to store and access translation files on CDN.
I want to access json or any **static file and which is on CDN**(content delivery network).
And that static file is private i.e. **not accessible by public URL**.
Need this solution for localization of an react app with quick response (hence storing static json file on CDN privately).
How can I access privately held file on CDN from react ?... is the main question

I tried i18next, **i18next-http-backend**.
It works with public file url.
I am not sure how to access private files from it.

Comment: pass an authorization header via customHeaders option or use locize.com with private publish option

Comment: @adrai can you please provide more insides on your solutions or any references if you have any ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [docs](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend#backend-options), you can pass customHeaders options...

[image]

This means you could do something like this:

```
import i18next from 'i18next';
import HttpApi from 'i18next-http-backend';

i18next.use(HttpApi).init({
  backend: {
    loadPath: 'https://path-to-your-private-cdn',
    customHeaders: {
      authorization: 'some secret or whatever you need to be authorized'
    }
  },
});
```

Or alternatively use a service that offers this, like [locize](https://locize.com):

```
import i18next from 'i18next';
import LocizeBackend from 'i18next-locize-backend';

i18next.use(LocizeBackend).init({
  backend: {
    projectId: "[PROJECTID]",
    apiKey: "[APIKEY]",
    version: "[VERSION]",
    private: true
  }
});
```